# PropertyGroupDescription CustomSort is missing the ItemCount in item X

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Preamble:
First I have searched stackoverflow and all of the topics pertaining to sorting grouped datagrids do not apply to this question.  In fact none of the answers actually show how to sort by group count without using 3rd partly libraries.

The Problem:
I am trying to sort my datagrid groups by count by overriding the CustomSort property of the PropertyGroupDescription.  When I assign a CustomSort method to the GroupDescription, the Compare function's object x CollectionViewGroup always has an ItemCount == 0.

Here is my sample xaml which is mostly taken from Microsoft's help:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="GroupedSorting.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GroupedSorting"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid
            Name="dg"
            Grid.Row="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemVMs}">

            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#FF112255" BorderBrush="#FF002255" Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
                <!-- Style for groups under the top level. -->
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel Background="LightBlue">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource completeConverter}}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace GroupedSorting
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> ItemVMs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            var r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ItemVMs.Add(new MyViewModel()
                {
                    Name = "Group 1",
                    MyIndex = r.Next()
                }); ;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                ItemVMs.Add(new MyViewModel()
                {
                    Name = "Group 2",
                    MyIndex = r.Next()
                });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                ItemVMs.Add(new MyViewModel()
                {
                    Name = "Group 3",
                    MyIndex = r.Next()
                });
            }

            List<MyViewModel> sortedItems = new List<MyViewModel>();
            var groups = ItemVMs.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
            foreach (var group in groups.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()))
            {
                sortedItems.AddRange(group);
            }
            ItemVMs.Clear();
            ItemVMs = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>(sortedItems);


            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sourceView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;
            var gd = new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(MyViewModel.Name));
            gd.CustomSort = new GroupComparer();
            sourceView.GroupDescriptions.Add(gd);
            sourceView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MyIndex { get; set; }
    }

    public class GroupComparer : System.Collections.IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            if (!(x is CollectionViewGroup xViewGroup))
                return 0;

            if (!(y is CollectionViewGroup yViewGroup))
                return 0;

            Debug.WriteLine($"{xViewGroup.Name} {xViewGroup.ItemCount}, {yViewGroup.Name} {yViewGroup.ItemCount}");

            if (xViewGroup.ItemCount < yViewGroup.ItemCount)
                return 1;
            else if (xViewGroup.ItemCount > yViewGroup.ItemCount)
                return -1;

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When the code is run, the xViewGroup.ItemCount is always equal to 0 causing the sort method to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `ICollectionView` returned from `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` to a `ListCollectionView` and set the `CustomSort` property of this one to your custom `IComparer`:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sourceView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;
    var gd = new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(MyViewModel.Name));
    sourceView.CustomSort = new GroupComparer();
    sourceView.GroupDescriptions.Add(gd);
    sourceView.Refresh();
}
```

[image]

Comment: That produces the same results.  The object x count is always 0.

Comment: I had to totally bail on Microsoft's implementation and instead sort in my view models.  So to change the sort order, the viewmodel is sorted then  the view is reloaded from scratch.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your issue but it works for me. But doing the sorting yourself is usually a good idea.

Comment: Did you try the sample code above?  It doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm not sure what error you are seeing, however I created a simple WPF app for .Net 4.7.2 then used the code above. It works for me so I need more information.

Comment: What is `completeConverter`?

Comment: I included an image of what I am seeing after running the code you have posted minus the converter part in the view, plus my implementation of `MainWindow_Loaded`. Aren't the groups sorted as expected? Or maybe I am misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: I always see the columns in the following order: 5,1,10.  When I step through the code I always see xViewGroup.ItemCount == 0.  Please try stepping rather than relying on the UI display.

Comment: I thought it was the UI that matters...What's your real issue then?

Comment: The UI does not sort properly.

Comment: In my example it does, doesn't it? 10, 5, 1.

Comment: What does your xViewGroup.ItemCount equal in the sorting algo? Mine is always 0.